# How can smart contracts / DAOs survive the chaos of the real world if they can't be easily updated?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency

Modern digital businesses work because, among other things, they can adapt to change. This is reflected in software development methods (Agile methodologies, etc.). Would Google have survived if it was still a simple search engine?

A smart-contract-based distributed autonomous organisation (DAO) is (if I'm not mistaken), initial, unchangeable, deterministic etc. How can we possibly expect the initial trajectory of a DAO through the nonlinearity and chaos of the real world to result in a useful, valuable, competitive service in 20 years' time if it can't update itself?

Answer (score 0):

The smart contract bytecode itself is immutable (except for few edge cases).

But many contracts implement the upgradable proxy pattern (see an [example](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-labs/blob/master/initializer_contracts_with_args/contracts/AdminUpgradeabilityProxy.sol) by OpenZeppelin). Which means that the client-facing contract itself only acts as a proxy to some implementation. And when it's time to upgrade, an authorized address can switch the proxy to point to a different implementation. This makes the service somewhat centralized, but allows for upgrading.

Some cryptocurrencies such as Bitcoin have more decentralized approach to upgrading. Anyone can submit a Bitcoin Improvement Proposal and when it's voted in, it gets implemented to the network. If a smart contract platform allows a similar way of upgrading smart contract (e.g. through voting on a change), it would also allow for a decentralized way of upgrading a smart contract.